# Issues with Installing Spacy Library

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying my hands on SPACY library for NLP and facing issues while installing. Following are the steps taken:

```
!pip3 install spacy
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I am getting following errors.

What needs to be done to fix it?

```
2021-03-10 14:12:10.063797: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-03-10 14:12:10.064255: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 428, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 472, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\_util.py", line 68, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 497, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 35, in download_cli
    download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 67, in download
    compatibility = get_compatibility()
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 78, in get_compatibility
    r = requests.get(about.__compatibility__)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

I also tried this option, but this is not working:

```
PS C:\Users\bj> pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
```

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github-releases.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /84940268/85ec3200-48aa-11e9-9878-337412e36828?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20210310%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210310T163448Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=1f872d0cc838d305c2ab952ec0a685a22a62894f38e0bd03b6920692d9755cce&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=84940268&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Den_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

Python version 3.8, Windows 10

Comment: I tried this option, but this is not working:

Comment: `pip install --upgrade certifi` can you try this?

Comment: Thanks for your response but does not work even after updating the certificate

Answer (score 2):

Add `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz` to your **requirements.txt** file.

Next, install using `pip3 install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host github.com -r requirements.txt`