# I am download spacy en_core_web_sm but it is show exception in my system What should i do?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

```
  File "C:\NLP Tasks\vnev\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\NLP Tasks\vnev\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002358940BEB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566576/issues-with-installing-spacy-library and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044628/cannot-install-en-core-web-sm-with-connection-error. Apparently it can help to try to install the models through alternative ways, see the spacy_models Github repository on this: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models#downloading-models.